# Timeframe of JSA in Stargirl

Tags: dc, arrowverse

The CW's Stargirl series features the JSA (Justice Society of America) in a major role.  It's made clear that the team had fought crime for quite some time, though they've been sketchy on exactly how long.  Newspaper clipping about past battles have no dates, for examples.

There's a couple of mentions of heroes and other teams from the fifties, such as the Red Bee.
[image]

And there's a mention that Dr. Charles McNider (AKA Dr. Mid-Nite) was born in 1914.

I'm curious what folks' opinions are as to how the timeline for the JSA works out in the show, and how much of the various youth-maintaining plot gimmicks from the comics you think will be revealed.

I'm reasonably confident that Pat Dugan is not a hundred years old, for example, and likely joined the JSA in the 80s or so, with Starman using the upgraded staff of the Original Starman, as he did in the comics.

Hoping that all this conjecture won't get the question bounced.